# Proof that $\oint_C 1dz = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need assitant in the following proof:

Let $C$ be a closed contour. Prove that
$$\oint_C 1dz = 0$$

Using this fact, prove that if $C'$ is any path that links $z_1$ to $z_2$, then
$$\int_C 1 \cdot dz = z_2 - z_1$$
therefore, this integral depends only on the starting and ending points, and not on the integration path which links these two points.

I've tried using Cauchy's Integral Theorem ($\oint_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$), but I failed to do so for $f(z) = 1$.

Could anyone offer any help?

Comment: What's preventing you from applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Each $dz$ can be thought of as a tangent vector to the curve, adding up all the tangent vectors, you get 0 since it forms a closed loop.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy's Integral Theorem is definitely the way to go here. $\mathbb{C}$ is star-shaped and $f: z \mapsto 1$ is definitely a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore the integral is 0. You can also imagine it this way:
For a closed contour $\gamma$, the integral is just given by $$\int_\gamma 1 dz = \int_a^b \gamma'(t)dt$$ so you are just adding many infinitesimal tangent vectors. But they have to cancel each other out in some way, since $\gamma$ is closed! Therefore the integral is 0.

For the second statement, if $\gamma$ is a curve connecting $z_1$ and $z_2$, try looking at $$\int_{\gamma \oplus {\gamma^-} 1 dz$$
where ${\gamma}^-$ is just $\gamma$ walked along in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy's Theorem seems a little overkill for evaluating this integral. I would simply notice that $w:=f(z)dz$, with $f(z):=1, \hspace{2mm} z \in \Bbb C$ is an exact form in $\Bbb C$ because it admits the primitive $dF$ with $F(z):=z, \hspace{2mm} z \in \Bbb C$; therefore any integral along a clodes and piecewise-differentiable curve in $\Bbb C$ must be $0$. As for your second point, you can again use the primitive in order to easily evaluate the integral; indeed, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the endpoints of a piecewise-differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $\Bbb C$, then:

$$ \int_{\gamma} w = F(z_2)-F(z_1) = z_2-z_1$$